# What is the difference between InputSource and InputStream?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, inputstream

What is the difference between using InputSource and InputStream when I am parsing xml.
I saw both examples in some tutorials

without InputSource:

```
InputStream is;
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

DocumentBuilder db = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = db.parse(is);
```

and with InputSource, where is the difference

```
DocumentBuilder db = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(is);
Document document = db.parse(inputSource);
```

So is there any difference in performance? Or in something else?

Comment: did you google your question? "difference between InputSource and InputStream ?" second answer ...

Comment: ye I did, sorry don't know why, I haven't found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253533/java-jaxp-xml-parsing-differences-of-documentbuilder) question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An `InputSource` can read from an `InputStream`, but it can also read from a `Reader` or direct from a URL (opening the stream itself).  Parsing from an `InputStream` is equivalent to parsing from a `new InputSource(theStream)`.

If the file you want to parse makes reference to an external DTD or any external entities by relative URIs then you can't parse it from a plain `InputStream`, as the parser doesn't know the base URL it should use to resolve these relative paths.  In that case you will need to construct an `InputSource` from the stream and use `setSystemId` to set the base URI and then parse from that source, rather than simply passing the stream direct to the parser.

Comment: Thanks for more information :) What I was looking for I found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253533/java-jaxp-xml-parsing-differences-of-documentbuilder)